# How to implement jquery table plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement a table sorter jquery plugin into my table. link to which is http://www.matanhershberg.com/plugins/jquery-animated-table-sorter/

But in the examples shown on the site, they have a table already . But for me it is not the case . For me, table comes up when I click a button the page . So, I wanted to ask that where should I add the javascript sort function given for sorting the table . So , that it gets sorted .

Comment: what you have tried?????

Comment: Actually, I cannot show the code ... . I did what is exactly said but it does not sort . I think that the problem is that table is coming after a click .So, I asked here. I m just a begineer in js .

Comment: Data of the table is coming as JSON . Will this make a difference as now I m able to click on the header of the table . But nothing is happening after clicking also .

Answer (score 0):

If you table is ajax'ed in when you click your button then in your ajax success callback function, after your draw your table, then apply the plugin...

```
//example jQuery ajax call
$.ajax({
    type: "[post or get]",
    url: "[your url]",
    data: $(".form").serialize(),
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        //your code that draws your table
        //now apply the plugin to your table
        $('table.tableSorter').tableSort( {
            sortBy: ['numeric', 'text', 'text', 'numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric']
        });
    }
});
```

But if your table is already in the page initially, but it's just hidden, then apply the plugin after the document is ready, just like the plugin demo page does.

Comment: there is a small form which have a submit button .As soon as it is clicked table comes up . I do not think table is ajaxed or hidden . Please help  <form id="fields" action="javascript:void(0);"> .

Comment: Sorry, need more info.  If it's not ajax'ed in then it must be there when the page loads.  When you click your button does the form submit to itself?  You need to show your code for us to help.